# Setup page on first login on multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, widgets, customization, signup

Is it possible to create a setup page on the first login before they visit their admin page to say change the language of the administrator and change their temporary password?

I don't want users to need to go to the 'Multisite Language Switcher' or go to 'Edit my Profile' when they first login to do these things.

I would like a window that appears after they first sign in to change these settings before they reach the admin site, so they are ready to go and post when they first enter the admin site.

If there are other things I can put on this setup page that would be good too.

Does this exist?